# Odd behavior regarding malloc()

Tags: c, malloc

Why does this work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char * abc = malloc(1) + 4; //WRONG use of malloc.
    char * xyz = "abc";
    strcpy(abc, xyz); //Should fail.
    printf("%s\n", abc); //Prints abc
}
```

I would expect the strcpy to fail for not having enough memory, as I'm passing in 1 to the argument of malloc(). Instead, this compiles and runs flawlessly (in both GCC on linux and dev c++ on Windows).

Is this expected behavior, or a happy coincidence?

**I assume this isn't good practice, but why does it work?**

Without the `+4` at the end of `malloc()`, I get a segmentation fault. This is mostly what I'm curious about.

Comment: That's not what "work" means.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Invoking undefined behaviour is always a bad idea. And there is no use in researching why code behaves a certain way once invoked. Not sure why you suspect not having enough memory to allocate 1 byte, but you might have some missconception about `malloc` & friends. And arithmetic on `void *` is also not defined.

Comment: I expect to have enough memory to allocate 1 byte, I don't expect to have enough for the strcpy to succeed.

Comment: You cannot perform pointer arithmetic on void pointers.

Comment: are you running on a system so constrained that it doesn't have 1 byte of free memory? you're accessigning/changing memory that hasn't been allocated, by virtue of fiddling with the address that malloc() returns. you're lucky it runs at all.

Comment: As for why there's space: `malloc` must return memory suitably aligned for `_Alignof(max_align_t)` (typically 16), so presumably it will get valid memory from the OS in units of 16B at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically another demonstration of the fact that pointers in C are low-level and (typically) not checked.  You said you expected it to "fail for not having enough memory", but think about it: what did you expect to fail?  The `strcpy` function most assuredly does not check that there's enough room for the string it's copying.  It has no way to do so; all it gets is a pointer.  It just starts copying characters, and in practice it either succeeds or dies on a segmentation violation.  (But the point is it does *not* die on "out of memory".)

Answer (score 6):

This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). **Don't do that!!**.

You're trying to access memory location beyond the allocated region. So, the memory location is *invalid* and accessing invalid memory invokes UB.

FWIW,

- there is noting in the C standard that *stops* you from accessing out of bound (invalid) memory and
- neither does `strcpy()` check for the size of the destination buffer compared to the source length

so, this code (somehow) compiles. As soon as you run it and it hits UB, nothing is guaranteed anymore.

*[P.S - the **only** guaranteed thing here is undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/2173917)*

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) about what could happen on *undefined behavior*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the link, embedded into my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on that behavior.  The answerers responding "vigorously" are justified in that relying on such behavior can lurk undetected for years and then, one day, a minor adjustment to the runtime system suddenly causes catastrophic failure.

It seems to work because, since the advent of 32-bit computers, many—if not most—C runtime libraries implement malloc/free which manage the heap with 16-byte granularity.  That is, calling `malloc()` with a parameter from 1 to 16 provides the same allocation.  SO you get a little more memory than you asked for and that allows it to execute.

A tool like `valgrind` would certainly detect a problem.